# React Native: Is there a callback function for when your app is closed?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a setInterval that keeps running even when you close (not quit) the app.  I would like to call a function when my app is closed or the device is put to sleep so that it clears the setInterval.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

itinance was close.  The answer is actually to use

```
AppState.addEventListener('change', state => {
  if (state === 'active') {
    // do this
  } else if (state === 'background') {
    // do that
  } else if (state === 'inactive') {
    // do that other thing
  }
});
```

Comment: This is only on iOS, doesnt work on Android

Comment: this does not fire when you close the app, only when you minimize it or change apps

Comment: did anyone find solution? 1) for android 2) does not fire when app close?

Answer (score 6):

AppState is your friend! Have a look at the [documentation of AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html).

So in your component, where the setTimeout exists, just require AppState and add an event listener like this:

```
AppState.addEventListener('background', this.handlePutAppToBackground);
AppState.addEventListener('inactive', this.handlePutAppToBackground);
```

handlePutAppToBackground() would be now a method in your component, where you would call clearTimeout(...)

Comment: docs for AppState include no mention of closing the app. When you minimize the app, or change apps, it runs the `background` state -which handles that AppState. If you "close" an app -AppState fires no changes

Comment: does not works!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding useEffect() without dependencies to the component where i want to emit a certain event when the component unmounts for any reason and in the clean up function emit the desired function.

```
useEffect(() => {
 return () => {
  The desired function
 }
})
```

Comment: add an empty dependency array (`[]`) to this useEffect, otherwise the function in return will run on every render!