# How to know if a react native app goes to background?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is it possible to know if a RN app has gone to background? Any callback or trigger?

If I listen to `componentDidUnmount` or `componentWillUnmount` of the screen I'm on, it will only be fired if I go back/forth to another screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native: Is there a callback function for when your app is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677137/react-native-is-there-a-callback-function-for-when-your-app-is-closed)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can listen to the `appState` event.
From https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native'

class AppStateExample extends Component {

  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!')
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>
    );
  }

}
```

By the way, this will always say 'Current state is: active', because that is the only state in which the app will be visible for the user.

Comment: Wouldn't that just always say 'current state is: active'

Comment: Note that this answer (and the [AppState example](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate) on React Native's official docs site) are out of date if you are using hooks. The issue is that the event listener is only added once, so it takes a snapshot of any state at that time and isn't updated afterwards, even if the event listener is called multiple times. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845595/wrong-react-hooks-behaviour-with-event-listener) for a detailed discussion.

Comment: iOS application goes from landscape to portrait while going to background and coming to foreground again, thanks to this method now I can switch back to landscape using `react-native-orientation`.

Comment: This answer shows how to listen for a foreground, not a background. It could be more clear.

Comment: removeListener is replaced by remove() in current version. We need to return this remove() in useEffect but how to call remove() in classCmoponent.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [`AppState`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html):

> App States
>
> - `active` - The app is running in the foreground
> - `background` - The app is running in the background. The user is either in another app or on the home screen
> - `inactive` - This is a state that occurs when transitioning between foreground & background, and during periods of inactivity such as entering the Multitasking view or in the event of an incoming call

Comment: Note that inactive only occurs on iOS

Comment: and heres the issue with just linking the documentation, as of this writing the example is broken if a reader clicked the provided link. https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate (removing the .html) from the original to fix at time of writing this.

Answer (score 0):

`AppState.removeEventListener` seems like deprecated, so I did this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { AppState } from 'react-native'

class AppStateClassComponent extends React.PureComponent {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            appState: ''
        }

        this.onAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
            if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
                console.log('App has come to the foreground!')
            }
            this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });
        }

        this.app_state = null
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.permission_check()
        if(this.app_state === null){
            this.app_state = AppState.addEventListener('change', this.onAppStateChange)
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if(this.app_state !== null){
            this.app_state?.remove()
            this.app_state = null
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>
        )
    }
}
```