# Wrong React hooks behaviour with event listener

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm playing around with *React Hooks* and am facing a problem.
It shows the wrong state when I'm trying to console log it using a button handled by event listener.

**CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/lrxw1wr97m

1. Click on *'Add card'* button 2 times
2. In first card, click on *Button1* and see in console that there are 2 cards in state (correct behaviour)
3. In first card, click on *Button2* (handled by event listener) and see in console that there is only 1 card in state (wrong behaviour)

Why does it show the wrong state? 
In first card, `Button2` should display `2` cards in the console. Any ideas?

```js
const { useState, useContext, useRef, useEffect } = React;

const CardsContext = React.createContext();

const CardsProvider = props => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  const addCard = () => {
    const id = cards.length;
    setCards([...cards, { id: id, json: {} }]);
  };

  const handleCardClick = id => console.log(cards);
  const handleButtonClick = id => console.log(cards);

  return (
    <CardsContext.Provider
      value={{ cards, addCard, handleCardClick, handleButtonClick }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </CardsContext.Provider>
  );
};

function App() {
  const { cards, addCard, handleCardClick, handleButtonClick } = useContext(
    CardsContext
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={addCard}>Add card</button>
      {cards.map((card, index) => (
        <Card
          key={card.id}
          id={card.id}
          handleCardClick={() => handleCardClick(card.id)}
          handleButtonClick={() => handleButtonClick(card.id)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function Card(props) {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.addEventListener("click", props.handleCardClick);
    return () => {
      ref.current.removeEventListener("click", props.handleCardClick);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="card">
      Card {props.id}
      <div>
        <button onClick={props.handleButtonClick}>Button1</button>
        <button ref={node => (ref.current = node)}>Button2</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <CardsProvider>
    <App />
  </CardsProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

I am using React 16.7.0-alpha.0 and Chrome 70.0.3538.110

BTW, if I rewrite the CardsProvider using a сlass, the problem is gone.
CodeSandbox using class: https://codesandbox.io/s/w2nn3mq9vl

Answer (score 170, accepted):

This is a common problem for functional components that use the `useState` hook. The same concerns are applicable to any callback functions where `useState` state is used, e.g. [`setTimeout` or `setInterval` timer functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024496/state-not-updating-when-using-react-state-hook-within-setinterval).

Event handlers are treated differently in `CardsProvider` and `Card` components.

`handleCardClick` and `handleButtonClick` used in the `CardsProvider` functional component are defined in its scope. There are new functions each time it runs, they refer to `cards` state that was obtained at the moment when they were defined. Event handlers are re-registered each time the `CardsProvider` component is rendered.

`handleCardClick` used in the `Card` functional component is received as a prop and registered once on component mount with `useEffect`. It's the same function during the entire component lifespan and refers to stale state that was fresh at the time when the `handleCardClick` function was defined the first time. `handleButtonClick` is received as a prop and re-registered on each `Card` render, it's a new function each time and refers to fresh state.

## Mutable state

A common approach that addresses this problem is to use `useRef` instead of `useState`. A ref is basically a recipe that provides a mutable object that can be passed by reference:

```
const ref = useRef(0);

function eventListener() {
  ref.current++;
}
```

In this case a component should be re-rendered on a state update like it's expected from `useState`, refs aren't applicable.

It's possible to keep state updates and mutable state separately but `forceUpdate` is considered an anti-pattern in both class and function components (listed for reference only):

```
const useForceUpdate = () => {
  const [, setState] = useState();
  return () => setState({});
}

const ref = useRef(0);
const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();

function eventListener() {
  ref.current++;
  forceUpdate();
}
```

## State updater function

One solution is to use a state updater function that receives fresh state instead of stale state from the enclosing scope:

```
function eventListener() {
  // doesn't matter how often the listener is registered
  setState(freshState => freshState + 1);
}
```

In this case a state is needed for synchronous side effects like `console.log`, a workaround is to return the same state to prevent an update.

```
function eventListener() {
  setState(freshState => {
    console.log(freshState);
    return freshState;
  });
}

useEffect(() => {
  // register eventListener once

  return () => {
    // unregister eventListener once
  };
}, []);
```

This doesn't work well with asynchronous side effects, notably `async` functions.

## Manual event listener re-registration

Another solution is to re-register the event listener every time, so a callback always gets fresh state from the enclosing scope:

```
function eventListener() {
  console.log(state);
}

useEffect(() => {
  // register eventListener on each state update

  return () => {
    // unregister eventListener
  };
}, [state]);
```

## Built-in event handling

Unless the event listener is registered on `document`, `window` or other event targets that are outside of the scope of the current component, React's own DOM event handling has to be used where possible, this eliminates the need for `useEffect`:

```
<button onClick={eventListener} />
```

In the last case the event listener can be additionally memoized with `useMemo` or `useCallback` to prevent unnecessary re-renders when it's passed as a prop:

```
const eventListener = useCallback(() => {
  console.log(state);
}, [state]);
```

- Previous edition of this answer suggested to use mutable state that was applicable to initial `useState` hook implementation in React 16.7.0-alpha version but isn't workable in final React 16.8 implementation. `useState` currently supports only immutable state.*

Comment: This issue is also explained in the React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function

Comment: `Manual event listener re-registration` - requires de-registration before each re-registration, to eliminate duplicate calls.

Comment: @vsync It's presumed that listeners are unregistered at some point because a component that doesn't do a cleanup is never wanted. There should already be unegistration code on unmount and yes, it should be executed multiple times in this case. Updated for clarity.

Comment: Note that you use "const" for your useRef(0) - Should be let otherwise it won't work - at least that was the difference in my case using React Native.

Comment: @mkkl Can you explain the case? Refs work a similar way in React. It should be `const` because this variable shouldn't be reassigned. It's ref `value` property that is changed, const/let isn't related to that

Answer (score 47):

A much cleaner way to work around this is to create a hook I call `useStateRef`

```
function useStateRef(initialValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const ref = useRef(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);

  return [value, setValue, ref];
}
```

You can now use the `ref` as a reference to the state value.

Comment: Does this ref value is the updated value ? or  the previous value?

Comment: @KamalHossain this method returns a reference for the current state value. You should refactor your states to [state, setState, stateRef] and use this method instead of useState(initialValue)

Comment: Why is the useEffect there? ref.current will be 1 value behind the current value on the render that the value changes. I think it is more correct to simply say `ref.current = value` - this is not taking into account the OP's question - just how this hook was formulated

Comment: This worked for me. In your eventListener just read ref.current

Answer (score 7):

Short answer for me was that useState has a simple solution for this:

```js
function Example() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  function update(updates) {
    // this might be stale
    setState({...state, ...updates});
    // but you can pass setState a function instead
    setState(currentState => ({...currentState, ...updates}));
  }

  //...
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing a bigger picture, what about if you don't want to setState you just want to consume the state to return a specific value or want to map over specific property of the state. Your answer is just a piece of a bigger answer.

Comment: @ncubica, absolutely, but the other answers all emphasize refs and effects, and I want to emphasize that you might not need them. I missed this the first time around.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer for me

> this ***WILL NOT*** not trigger re-render ever time myvar changes.

```
const [myvar, setMyvar] = useState('')
  useEffect(() => {    
    setMyvar('foo')
  }, []);
```

> This ***WILL*** trigger render -> putting **myvar in []**

```
const [myvar, setMyvar] = useState('')
  useEffect(() => {    
    setMyvar('foo')
  }, [myvar]);
```

Comment: No, both **WILL** trigger rerender, it's just that the first `useEffect` will fire once - on components mount, while the second one will fire every time `myvar` updates.

Answer (score 3):

Check the console and you'll get the answer:

`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props.handleCardClick'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)`

Just add `props.handleCardClick` to the array of dependencies and it will work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

To build off of [Moses Gitau's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58439475/409958), if you are developing in Typescript, to resolve type errors make the hook function generic:

```js
function useStateRef<T>(initialValue: T | (() => T)): 
   [T, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>, React.MutableRefObject<T>] {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initialValue);

  const ref = React.useRef(value);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);

  return [value, setValue, ref];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This way your callback will have updated state values always ;)

```
 // registers an event listener to component parent
 React.useEffect(() => {

    const parentNode = elementRef.current.parentNode

    parentNode.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleAutoClose)

    return () => {
        parentNode.removeEventListener('mouseleave', handleAutoClose)
    }

}, [handleAutoClose])
```

Comment: Awesome! This helped me a lot, thanks. I had an issue with my pinch to zoom func.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the answer of @Moses Gitau, I'm using a sligthly different one that doesn't give access to a "delayed" version of the value (which is an issue for me) and is a bit more minimalist:

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';

function useStateRef(initialValue) {
    const [, setValueState] = useState(initialValue);

    const ref = useRef(initialValue);

    const setValue = (val) => {
        ref.current = val;
        setValueState(val); // to trigger the refresh
    };

    const getValue = (val) => {
        return ref.current;
    };

    return [getValue , setValue];
}
export default useStateRef;
```

This is what I'm using

Example of usage :

```
const [getValue , setValue] = useStateRef(0);

const listener = (event) => {
    setValue(getValue() + 1);
};

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keyup', listener);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('keyup', listener);
    };
}, []);
```

Edit : It now gives getValue and not the reference itself. I find it better to keep things more encapsulated in that case.

Answer (score -1):

after changing the following line in the `index.js` file the `button2` works well:

```
useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.addEventListener("click", props.handleCardClick);
    return () => {
        ref.current.removeEventListener("click", props.handleCardClick);
    };
- }, []);
+ });
```

you should not use `[]` as 2nd argument `useEffect` unless you want it to run once.

more details: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: This behaviour is equivalent to componentDidUpdate and on every re-render the eventListener would be removed and then recreated which is unnecessary and would be a performance hit. One can either add a dependency to the cards so that adding and removal of event listener would not be much or use useRef to get the mutable value of the cards.