# Do we still need functional setState way in react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```js
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = () =>
    setCount(prevCount => {
      return prevCount + 1;
    });
```

```js
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => setCount(count + 1);
```

Coming from class-based component background, it becoming a habit where we use functional `setState`. I'm wondering if do we still need to rely on prevState in functional hooks? Or the current state is always "trustable" and most "updated"?

Comment: Yes, we do. No, current state isn't trustable, less than ever before. See for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845595/wrong-react-hooks-behaviour-with-event-listener

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Yes**, the behavior is similar.

React is batching the updates calls.
When Writing:

```
const handleClick = () => setCount(count + 1)
handleClick()
handleClick()
handleClick()
```

the `count` in state will be 1

When Writing:

```
const handleClick = () =>
  setCount(prevCount => {
    return prevCount + 1;
});
handleClick()
handleClick()
handleClick()
```

the `count` in state will be 3

Comment: Thanks, this example makes it very clear how this works. This explains why a toggle function in my component isn't working correctly when trying to logically NOT a boolean value stored in state.

Answer (score 3):

[State updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is necessary in both class and functional components. `this.setState` shouldn't be used together with `this.state`, the same applies to `useState` state and state setter. There are more cases for `useState` when not using state updater will result in wrong behaviour.

In class components, the only problem with the use of `this.state` is race condition due to asynchronous state updates:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 }); // overwrites with stale count
  console.log(this.state.count); // not updated
}
```

When there are no race conditions, `this.state` can be accessed anywhere inside a component because `this` reference stays the same:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }, 100)

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(this.state.count);
  }, 200)
}
```

In functional components, the problem with the use of `useState` state is function scope. There's no object like this that could be accessed by reference, a state is accessed by value which won't be updated until a component is re-rendered:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  // runs once on mount
  // count is always 0 in this function scope

  setCount({ count: count + 1 });

  setTimeout(() => {
    setCount({ count: count + 1 }); // overwrites with stale count
  }, 100)

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(count); // not updated
  }, 200)
}, []);
```