# question about using arrow function inside the setstate function of useState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use reactHook from an example like this;

```
const [newAccount, setNewAccount] = useState(true);
const toggleAccount = () => {
    setNewAccount((prev) => !prev);
}
```

newAccount is to tell whether the user already has on account, and made an event to function to toggle the status of NewAccount.

I thought in setNewaccount ,I should put a value as param like;
`setNewAccount(!newAccount);` 
It works, but the example puts an arrow function `((prev)=>!prev);`,and still it does work too. I am quite confused as why it works.

In my opinion, by using setNewAccount like that doesnt newAccount become a function `{{prev)=>!prev}`, not the boolean value that I originally thought?

Comment: State setters in React can take callback functions where the argument of the function is the previous stateful value. This can be helpful if you want to ensure the state setter is run on the most current version of state rather than having closure around the state in its outer scope

Comment: You can pass a value or a function to `setState`, the second parameter returned by `useState`. If you pass a value, you set the updated value and if you pass a function, you get `prevState` as its function parameter. it is recommended to use function approach if you are using prevState while updating state

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55510565/do-we-still-need-functional-setstate-way-in-react-hooks

Comment: I was also searching for the same doubt, thank you @Nick best explanation.

Comment: in your last paragraph you meant {(prev)=>!prev}