# React hooks - setState is not updating the state properties to show sidebar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a event when you resize the window will show desktop sidebar or mobile sidebar. if window is less than  But there are variables that aren't updated immediately to show sidebar if I'm in desktop window, I could that with class

I've created a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/sidebar-hooks-8oefi 
to see the code, I have the class component in App_class.js which if I replace in App it works, but with hooks (App_hooks.js file, by default in App.js) I can't make it works

Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply.

with class I could do that using:

```
if (isMobile !== wasMobile) {
   this.setState({
      isOpen: !isMobile
   });
}
```

```
 const App = props => {
  //minicomponent to update width
  const useListenResize = () => {
    const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [isMobile, setMobile] = useState(true);
    //const [previousWidth, setPreviousWidth] = useState( -1 );

    let previousWidth = -1;

    const updateWidth = () => {
      const width = window.innerWidth;
      const widthLimit = 576;
      let newValueMobile = width <= widthLimit;
      setMobile(isMobile => newValueMobile);
      const wasMobile = previousWidth <= widthLimit;

      if (isMobile !== wasMobile) {
        setOpen(isOpen => !isMobile);
      }
      //setPreviousWidth( width );
      previousWidth = width;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      updateWidth();
      window.addEventListener("resize", updateWidth);
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", updateWidth);
      };
      // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, []);

    return isOpen;
  };

  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(useListenResize());

  const toggle = () => {
    setOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App wrapper">
      <SideBar toggle={toggle} isOpen={isOpen} />
      <Container fluid className={classNames("content", { "is-open": isOpen })}>
        <Dashboard toggle={toggle} isOpen={isOpen} />
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

with setState didn't work

Comment: Where is your hook? Don't mix hooks with `setState`.

Comment: sorry instead of setState which if for classes is useState, the hook useEffect is inside useListenResize function and useState too

Comment: @AA, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is after setting `isMobile` value here,

```
setMobile(isMobile => newValueMobile);
```

You are immediately refering that value,

```
if (isMobile !== wasMobile) {
   setOpen(isOpen => !isMobile);
}
```

Due to `async` nature of `setState`, your are getting previous value of `isMobile` here all the times.

To make this work you need to make some change to your code.

You are directly mutating `previousWidth` value, you should have `previousWidth` in a state and use setter function to change the value.

```
const [previousWidth, setPreviousWidth] = useState(-1);

setPreviousWidth(width);  //setter function
```

You cannot get value immediately after `setState`. You should use another `useEffect` with `isMobile` and `previousWidth` as dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
   const wasMobile = previousWidth <= widthLimit;
   if (isMobile !== wasMobile) {
     setOpen(isOpen => !isMobile);
   }
}, [isMobile, previousWidth]);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sidebar-hooks-ej2ff?fontsize=14)

Comment: I get better how it's working and how to access to the state from useEffect and it works! thank you very much! after that I'll do some research and try to figure out how to solve the issue when you use : setPreviousWidth(width); this update the value from -1 to your actual windows size (normal windows on desktop) and because of that when page loads never show sidebar because setOpen is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Since `updateWidth` is registered once on component mount with useEffect, then it will refer to a **stale** state (`isMobile`), which is always true, therefore, `setOpen(isOpen => !isMobile)` will never work.

EDIT: The following [code](https://codepen.io/helaoutar/pen/YzKMRjo?editors=1010) illustrates a simpler version of your issue:

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  const logCount = () => {
    console.log(count);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
     window.addEventListener('resize', logCount);
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you run this code, you will notice that even if you change the value of `count` by clicking on the button, you will always get the initial value when resizing the browser (check the console), and that's because `logCount` refer to a state that was obtained at the moment it was defined.

@ravibagul91 answer works, because it access the state from `useEffect`, and not from the event handler.

You may wanna check: [React hooks behaviour with event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845595/wrong-react-hooks-behaviour-with-event-listener) and [Why am I seeing stale props or state inside my function?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function), it will give you a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: thank you, I'll read that to get better about this, hooks gets more complex when there are events listeners on the way