# Why doesn't my React program get the most recent version of the state variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am working on [a program](https://github.com/dhappy/housing/tree/react) which fetches a SVG and converts it into a set of React components with some interactivity.

The problem I am having is the `onClick` handler that I register when building the tree is not getting the updated version of my state variables.

In my `buildTree` function, I have the following code:

```js
⋮
if(["key"].includes(attrs.className)) {
  setKeys((ks) => [...ks, attrs.ref])
  attrs.onClick = (evt) => clickShow(evt.target, attrs.ref.current)
}

return React.createElement(root.nodeName, attrs, children)
```

When I click, however, the `keys` variable an empty array.

[This pen](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-scoping-issue-r4gki?file=/src/App.js) demonstrates the issue. The key is the little picture of a house in the lower left-hand corner. Clicking on a floor should change the view, but as you can see in the console, `keys` is an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53846698/264008) which explains the scoping issue I'm having and that I can use `useRef` to get a properly mutable variable.