# Why this navigation.goBack is not working as I intended ? How can I get the Last Active State?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I got 3 pages

`homepage`, `productList` and `productDetails`

When going from `homepage` to `productList` I pass a route param,

```
navigation.navigate('productList', { showCategory: 'productListA'} )
```

***`InitialProcess when component mounted`***

Inside the productList page when the component is mounted. I am declaring use state like this.

```
const {showCateory} = route.params;
const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(showCateory);
```

and calling api using that activeTab

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      async function fetchData() {
        try {
          await dispatch(
            fetchProductList(
              activeTab,
            ),
          );
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } 
      }
      fetchData();
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

***`User Interaction`***

But I also add the button in the productList so that user can ***change*** the current active tab

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => changeTab()}></TouchableOpacity>

const changeTab = async () => {
 await setActiveTab('productListB'),
 await dispatch(fetchProductList(activeTab)
}
```

Take note that right now `active tab` and `data coming from api is different` from when the component is start mounted.

***`Navigation Change again`***

When use goes from `productList` to `productDetails`. All thing is fine.

But inside the product details I am going back to productList with this.
`navigation.goBack()`.

When I am back in productList page The activeTab is change back to `productListA` and the data is change back to when `component is mounted`

Can I pass or change the route params when calling `navigation.goBack()`?

Comment: where are you calling setActiveTab ? Post full code.

Comment: @JanakNirmal setActiveTab is user interaction. So This will call when user press a button.

Comment: Seems like the 'focus' callback still has the activeTab value of the initial render. Can you try using useRef and setting its current value to the activeTab. Then use the ref object inside the 'focus' callback.

Answer (score 2):

add `activeTab` in useEffect depedineces.

as docs say

> The array of dependencies is not passed as arguments to the effect function. Conceptually, though, that’s what they represent: every value referenced inside the effect function should also appear in the dependencies array. In the future, a sufficiently advanced compiler could create this array automatically.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      async function fetchData() {
        try {
          await dispatch(
            fetchProductList(
              //this value will always updated when activeTab change
              activeTab,
            ),
          );
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } 
      }
      fetchData();
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [activeTab]); //<<<<< here
```

also you need to know setState() does not always immediately update the component. see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)
so change this

```js
const changeTab = async () => {
 //await setActiveTab('productListB'),
 //await dispatch(fetchProductList(activeTab)

 setActiveTab('productListB')
 dispatch(fetchProductList('productListB'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because `route.params` is still set to `{ showCategory: 'productListA'}`  when you are coming back to the screen.

If this is the case, you can fix it by Changing `params` object in  `changeTab()` like

```
navigation.setParams({
  showCategory: 'productListB',
});
```

I hope this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the callback function inside the focus listener uses the initial value of the state when the function was defined (at initial page render) . Throughout the lifespan of listener the callback function uses this stale state value.You can read more about this behaviour in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53846698/7470531)

Although the answer by Ahmed Gaber works in this case as the listener is cleared and redefined after each state change.Another common work-around is to use an useRef instead of useEffect.A ref is basically a recipe that provides a mutable object that can be passed by reference.

In your case you can initialise activeTab with navigation param value using useRef hook as :

```js
const activeTab = useRef(showCateory);
```

and the focus listener callback function should be changed to use the Reference current value as

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      async function fetchData() {
        try {
          await dispatch(
            fetchProductList(
              activeTab.current, //<<<<<<---------here
            ),
          );
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } 
      }
      fetchData();
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

and the changeTab function can directly update reference current value

```js
const changeTab = async () => {
 setActiveTab.current = 'productListB';
 dispatch(fetchProductList('productListB'))
}
```