# How can I schedule a task in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native

In my use case user can schedule a task at any date and time and when the time approaches if user is active(or app is at foreground) the task will start automatically if not a notification appears to begin the task

i have almost achieved that with react native push notification library i'm able to schedule a local notification but there is no support for on receive of scheduled local notification(https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1662)
so when using this library even when app is active user have to click the notification to start the task

is there a way to properly schedule a task such that if app is active at that time it has to automatically start the task

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to schedule a task in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946431/what-is-the-best-way-to-schedule-a-task-in-react-native)

Comment: No i don't have anything to run in background even if i use  background setTimeout in my case a user can schedule n number of schedules  and user may kill app completely  which stops the timeout which is not efficient and reliable

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution could be to save tasks locally using [AsyncStorage](https://react-native-community.github.io/async-storage/).

Then you could use react-native-background-timer for background code execution. More on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57658950/how-to-call-function-when-app-in-foreground-or-background-in-react-native).

Then you will be able to periodically check AsyncStorage for tasks. Each task would have a hh:mm value. If current time would be the same as one event then you would execute some code.

When times are equal you could check for [AppState](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate.html) and react :P based on that.

I have no experience with background timer so I cannot guarantee validity of this solution.